# Using ForeignKey of Django CustomUser giving attribute error

Tags: django, django-views

Not using Djnago Default user model. Have created a Custom user model named CustomUser

```
    class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):

GENDER_CHOICE = (
    ('MALE', 'MALE'),
    ('FEMALE', 'FEMALE'),
)

BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICE = (
    ('A+', 'A+'),
    ('B+', 'B+'),
    ('O+', 'O+'),
    ('AB+', 'AB+'),
    ('A-', 'A-'),
    ('B-', 'B-'),
    ('O-', 'O-'),
    ('AB-', 'AB-'),
)

RELIGION_CHOICE = (
    ('ISLAM', 'ISLAM'),
    ('HINDU', 'HINDU'),
    ('CHRISTIANITY', 'CHRISTIANITY'),
    ('OTHER', 'OTHER'),


)

email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, verbose_name='Email')
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='First Name')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Last Name')
gender = models.CharField(_("Employee Gender"),
                          max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICE, null=True, blank=True)
blood_group = models.CharField(
    _("Employee Blood Group"), max_length=3, choices=BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICE, null=True, blank=True)
birth_of_date = models.DateField(
    _("Employee Birth Date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
#address = models.CharField(_("Employee Address"), max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
address = models.CharField(_("Employee Address"), max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(_("Employee Profile Picture"), upload_to='profile_pic',
                                height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None, null=True, blank=True)
religion = models.CharField(
    _("Employee Religion"), max_length=15, choices=RELIGION_CHOICE, null=True, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('first_name', 'last_name')

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.first_name

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return self.is_admin

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Shunno ek Users"
```

Here is my CumstomUser models' CustomUsermanager

```
    class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('You must have an email')

    email = email.lower()
    first_name = first_name.title()
    last_name = last_name.title()

    user = self.model(
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
        first_name = first_name,
        last_name = last_name
    )

    #user.password = password
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)

    return user


def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        email = email,
        first_name = first_name,
        last_name = last_name,
        password = password
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.save(using=self._db)

    return user
```

This is a model of saving users Quiz answers.

```
    class UserAns(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quiz_user')
quizcat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
totalq = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
correcta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.User.first_name
```

It is view part where i want to save the data of user answer.
def quizpage(request, slug):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # totalquestion
    solve = 0
    for question in range(1,cat.totalq+1):
        entered_answer_questionpk = request.POST.get(str(question))
        ans = entered_answer_questionpk[:1]
        qpk = int(entered_answer_questionpk[1:])
        actualans = Question.objects.get(pk=qpk).correct_answer
        if ans == actualans:
            solve = solve + 1 
    # print(user)
    usersans = UserAns(totalq=cat.totalq, correcta=solve)
    
    
    usersans.quizcat = cat
    print(request.user)
    usersans.user = request.user
    usersans.save()


return render(request, 'quiz/quizpage.html',{'questions': questions })
```

after saving this value in the database, when I click the table name it gives this error:

```
    Django Version: 3.1.3
    Exception Type: AttributeError
    Exception Value:    
   'UserAns' object has no attribute 'User'
```

I can't understand where is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string method is referencing `self.User` and not `self.user`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.first_name
```

Previous answer:

You should also look through your view that's rendering the page and protect any parts that access `userans.user` via `if hasattr(userans, 'user'):` or `if userans.user_id:`.

Another thing you can do is clean up your data. Your post view looks to be about right. But that page is failing because you have instances that still have the user property with a value of `None`.Open up a shell `manage.py shell`, import your `UserAns` model and see if you have any instances without a user. If you do, determine which user(s) they should map to or delete them.

```
UserAns.objects.filter(user__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother. Loved your explanation.